# vagrant box SSL error "suddenly" (Windows 10 + 7)

Tags: vagrant

I have had this vagrant file for close to a year and never gave me issues:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  #config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet"  
  config.vm.box = "alex-barylski/debian-8.2"    

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8089
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 33002

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y puppet puppet-common 

    # Required for the file_* function in platform include
    puppet module install puppetlabs/stdlib 
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"    
    puppet.manifests_path = ".vagrant/puppet"
    puppet.module_path = ".vagrant/puppet/modules"

    #puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", owner: "vagrant", group: "www-data", mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]         
end
```

Here is the result:

> ==> default: Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u2) ...
>   ==> default: /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default: :
>   ==> default: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.so: symbol SSLv2_method, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file
>   libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference -
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.so
>   ==> default:  (
>   ==> default: LoadError
>   ==> default: )
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/monkey_patches.rb:171:in`'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:16:in `<module:Util>'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:15:in`'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet.rb:8:in`'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/command_line.rb:12:in `<top
>   (required)>'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require'
>   ==> default:    from /usr/bin/puppet:7:in`' The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means
>   the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log
>   above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.

If I downgrade to debian 7.8 it seems to work - but I need 8.2. I have tried 3-4 different boxes, manually downloaded, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Update Oct 2016**

As of the end of Sept 2016 a new version of the Debian Jessie boxes became available on Atlas, which also fixes this problem for us.

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/debian/boxes/jessie64/versions/8.6.1

**Original Answer**

Same problem over here, it seems that Puppet or Ruby have been upgraded to use newer versions of `libssl` as the ones available in the box. If we do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y upgrade
```

manually in the box suddenly `puppet apply` of our manifest is back to normal. Here is the fix for your `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  #config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-8.2-64-puppet"  
  config.vm.box = "alex-barylski/debian-8.2"    

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8089
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 33002

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL

     apt-get update
     apt-get -y upgrade libssl1.0.0 openssl # forces an upgrade of libssl and openssl
     apt-get install -y puppet puppet-common 

     # Required for the file_* function in platform include
     puppet module install puppetlabs/stdlib 
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"    
    puppet.manifests_path = ".vagrant/puppet"
    puppet.module_path = ".vagrant/puppet/modules"

    #puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", owner: "vagrant", group: "www-data", mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]         
end
```

Downside of this approach in our case we spin up around 10 machines this consumes a lot of bandwidth and time.